# Receive messages only from a specific DDS topic instance?

Tags: ace, data-distribution-service, tao

I'm using OpenDDS v3.6, and trying to send a message to a specific DDS peer, one of many. In the IDL, the message structure looks like the following:

```
module Test
{
#pragma DCPS_DATA_TYPE "Test::MyMessage"
#pragma DCPS_DATA_KEY "Test::MyMessage dest_id"
    struct MyMessage {
        short dest_id;
        string txt;
    };
};
```

My understanding is that because the data key is unique, this is a new instance of the topic being written to, and any further msgs written w/ the same data key send to this specific instance of the topic. My send code is as follows:

```
DDS::ReturnCode_t ret;
Test::MyMessage msg;

// populate msg
msg.dest_id = n;

DDS::InstanceHandle_t handle;

handle = msg_writer->register_instance(msg);

ret = msg_writer->write(msg, handle);
```

So now I need to figure out how to get the receiving peer to read only from this topic instance and not receive all the other messages being sent to other peers. I started with the following, but not sure how to properly select a specific topic instance.

```
DDS::InstanceHandle_t instance;

status = msg_dr->take_next_instance(spec, si, 1, DDS::ANY_SAMPLE_STATE, 
    DDS::ANY_VIEW_STATE, DDS::ANY_INSTANCE_STATE);
```

Any help much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to achieve what you are looking for is by using a `ContentFilteredTopic`. This class is a specialization of the `TopicDescription` class and allows you to specify an expression (like a SQL `WHERE`-clause) of the samples that you are interested in.

Suppose you want your `DataReader` to only receive samples with `dest_id` equal to 42, then the corresponding code for creating the `ContentFilteredTopic` would look something like

```
DDS::ContentFilteredTopic_var cft =
              participant->create_contentfilteredtopic("MyTopic-Filtered",
                                                       topic,
                                                       "dest_id = 42",
                                                       StringSeq());
```

From there on, you create your `DataReader` using `cft` as the parameter for the `TopicDescription`. The resulting reader will look like a regular `DataReader`, except that it only receives the desired samples and nothing else. Since the field `dest_id` happens to be the field that identifies the instance, the end result is that you will only have one instance in your DataReader.

You can check out the [DDS specification](http://www.omg.org/spec/DDS/1.2/PDF/) (section 7.1.2.3.3) or [OpenDDS Developer's Guide](http://download.ociweb.com/OpenDDS/OpenDDS-latest.pdf) (section 5.2) for more details.

Comment: Thanks, I'll change this out to ContentFiltered then. However, is my understanding of topic instances wrong? Whats the purpose of a new instance based on the key if a peer is going to receive all samples of all instances of that type? Can peers not read a single instance?

Comment: And if I understand the class specialization correctly, this is TopicDecscription, not Topic as you have. So I assume thats just a typo, or please correct me.

Comment: Your understanding of topic instances might be wrong indeed... The purpose of a new instance based on the key is that each instance of the Topic can have its own CRUD life-cycle. In that light, you can compare a Topic to a database table and the instances to the rows in that table. In some cases, a peer might be interested in all rows (for example, all trucks in a fleet) but in other cases, a peer might be interested in a single row (for example if used for request/reply).

Comment: You also asked "Can peers not read a single instance?" -- yes they can, that is what the ContentFilteredTopic is for. Note that read_instance() (and the related instance functions) can be used for reading a single instance out of the pool of instances in a DataReader. This will not avoid the delivery of other instances to the DataReader though. You need the ContentFilteredTopic for that.

Comment: You are right about the TopicDescription base class, thanks. I corrected it.